# OpenGeo: suite-sdk command not found

Tags: boundless-suite, sdk

I'm trying to install and run the Boundless SDK according to:
http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/webapps/install.html. I've tried running:

> $ suite-sdk
>   bash: /usr/bin/suite-sdk: Permission denied
>   $ sudo suite-sdk // with and without the help and create commands
>   sudo: suite-sdk: command not found

So I know that I am calling suite-sdk from the right place. I have jdk6 and Ant both installed.

> java version "1.6.0_33"
>   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.5) (6b33-1.13.5-1ubuntu0.12.04)
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
>   Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 3 2011

My /etc/environment files is:

> PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
>   JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin"

(I've also tried the JAVA_HOME path with and without /bin and /jre)

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to manually give the command execute permissions with chmod, this will be fixed in the upcoming release, see https://github.com/boundlessgeo/suite/issues/611 for more info

Comment: Thank you! I had to chmod the suite-sdk executable, rather than it's shortcut in the usr/bin folder. As well as add an ANT_HOME to etc/environment. Thanks for the help!